# Efficiently computing a matrix's induced p-norm

Tags: matrices

Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ real matrix and we need to find $\left\|A\right\|_p$ for $p \notin \{ 1, 2, \infty \}$. What is the most efficient way to compute $\left\|A\right\|_p$?

Here's one naive approach I can think of. Sample random points $\left\|x\right\|$ on the unit hypersphere  , computing $\left\|Ax\right\|_p$ for each such and take the maximum. What I would like to know is the runtime of this approach for the "average" A, and how we can optimize this for special classes of matrices (like Diagonal, Orthonormal, etc.)?

Comment: By $\Vert A \Vert_p$, do you mean the norm from $\ell_p$ to $\ell_p$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the negative side, there is a [result](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1397) by myself and Julien Hendrickx that the matrix $p$-norm is NP-hard to approximate whenever $p$ is not $1,2,$ or $\infty$.

On the positive side, the [M.S. thesis of Daureen Steinberg](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/Daureen.pdf) has an efficient algorithm for computing the $p$-norm of a nonnegative matrix (see Remark 3.4 on page 48).

Answer (score 7):

S.W. Drury derives a method to find the operator norm of a general real matrix 
$$
A : \ell^p \longrightarrow \ell^q
$$
in a recent 
[paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379511000589) 
in *Lin. Alg. Appl* (and using it, refutes a long-standing conjecture of Matsaev).

In keeping with the answer of Alex Olshevsky, the algorithm seems have a complexity exponential in the number of columns of the matrix (but linear in the number of rows).

Drury's implementation for Visual C++ and Maple can be found [here](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/drury/research/matsaev/matsaev.html), and a C version targeted at Unix and with bindings for Matlab, Octave and Python can be found 
[here](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/jjg/en/code/steckin.html).

Answer (score 5):

Nicholas Higham gives an [algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01396242) for *estimating* the Hölder $p$-norm of a matrix with the estimate being within a factor of $n^{1-1/p} \|\mathbf{A}\|_p$  ; maybe you can somehow adapt this approach to your needs?

---

(added 5/13/2011)

I posted a *Mathematica* translation of Higham's [original MATLAB code](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/test_matrix/pnorm.m) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37913/37939#37939).