# Easy and Hard problems in Mathematics

Tags: examples, soft-question, big-list, foundations

Modified question:

I would like to know some examples of problems in Mathematics, for pedagogical purposes, which do not involve difficult techiques to solve the problem but with a change of context turns them into monstrous-unimaginably difficult to solve problems.

By changing the context I mean, by changing one class of objects in the problem to a related 
class of objects. For example, from directed graph to undirected graph or Zygmund class to 
Log-lipshitz class. By changing a 'less-than problem' to 'greater-than problem'. From 2-case 
problem to 3-case problem. There are plenty of such examples in Theoretical Computer Science or Computational Complexity theory. I need some examples in Mathematics. Lot of examples fall in this category but I am looking for only extreme examples like the ones I stated below. Since, this question is asked for pedagogical purpose it would be interesting if there is a story behind the problem.

Examples of problems:

- Linear Programming to integer linear programming
- 2-coloring to 3-coloring
- Eulerian graph to Hamiltonian graph
- Undirected graph case to directed graph case in Shannon's switching game
- 2-SAT to 3-SAT

One thought which motivated me to pose this question is: what if Konigsberg problem has been
formulated as a vertex problem. Would Leonard Euler get inspried to create graph theory? No 
doubt, history speaks differently as Konigsberg problem is stated in terms of edges. Not only
Euler solved this problem but created a branch of mathematics out of it! And I am not sure what turn of events would have taken place had the problem been posed in terms of vertices.

IMHO, there are look-alike easy problems and hard problems coexisting but it is the easy problems which saved mathematicians day and hard ones which gave them incentive to work harder.

Some pointers for hardness of problem: problems which need sophisticated tools, techniques which diverge from the routine ones, radical thinking or bold ideas to solve the them, like Poincare conjecture. Or, those problems which do not have adequate tools yet to attempt them, like (NP=P?).

I would appreciate any answers in this direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing the words "small change" are
I'll defined enough to get this question closed. That being said, when you prove theorems, you have some assumptions on the objects of study, in a huge number of cases removing an assumption makes the theorem not just more difficult, but plain wrong. But it's at a fundamental level. An example of this is Fermat's Last theorem(I went with the most obvious example possible), if you take R or C rather than Z, solutions exist and the proof is fairly straightforward. 

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the term 'small change' is vague. In fact, I thought about it while posing the question. The small change what I mean is in the hypothesis, like relaxing compactness assumptions or changing the space from Zygmund class of functions to Log-lipschitz class, or the example I stated in thee question linear programming to integer linear programming that is looking for a solution in integers and not in real numbers. So, I feel this is a suitable question in MO.

Comment: Also, I feel there is a thin line in changing the theorem from making it harder to wrong one. All the more this has to interest mathematicians. If we already know which conjectures are correct/ wrong or easy/hard then why try proving them. The easy or hard I ask is in terms of the human effort-what we perceive as easy or hard. May be Fermats last theorem is easy for somebody from Mars.

Comment: I just voted to close as "not a real question" but in hindsight I think "subjective and argumentative" is nearer the mark. A lot of these so-called small changes are in fact BIG changes, in my opinion.

Comment: Saying that they are not 'small changes' but 'big changes' is fair. Thanks. May be I could have said 'seemingly small'. Anyway, I thought it would be an interesting story to hear and tell my students about the way hypothesis impacts the results. The dangers of not being careful about a hypothesis. 

Comment: If the change from "wanting real solutions" to "wanting integer solutions" seems small, then one may need stronger lenses.

Comment: I assume "4-coloring" is meant to be "2-coloring".

Comment: I take it you are hoping to get the question reopened. Perhaps you should start a thread on the meta site where there could be a discussion of how the question might be made more acceptable on MO. I'm not sure that a change in the title suffices. 

Comment: Meta discussion - http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1314/changing-a-question-to-make-it-acceptable-question-89556 

Comment: I think this question is interesting from the pedagogical point of view, since these are the kind of "gore" examples that make students realise that "seemingly small changes" can perfectly be not small at all.

Comment: The classification of finite dimensional vector spaces is boring; the classification of such vector spaces: with one endomorphism is interesting (canonical forms for square matrices);  with two endomorphisms is hard; and with three is unknown. (the last two come under "so I am told!")

Comment: Harvey Friedman has developed results of the following form: Theorem A is a result provable in Peano arithmetic and hence an easy theorem. Theorem B is a slight modification of theorem A, however Theorem B implies the consistency of large cardinals and therefore Theorem B cannot be proven within ZFC so Theorem B is hard.

Answer (score 6):

Finding the $\ell_p$ operator norm of a matrix is easy for $p=1,2,\infty$, but it is NP-hard for any other $p$ (see [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39148/), for example).

Answer (score 3):

Changing $L^2$ convergence to almost everywhere convergence (of the Fourier series of an $L^2$ function) takes (essentially) the rather easy Riesz-Fischer theorem into the very hard Carleson's theorem.

Comment: This is very common, for example the mean ergodic theorem (Von-Neumann) vs. the pointwise ergodic theorem (Birkhoff).

Comment: Always good to see love for Carleson's theorem, but I would debate that this is a "small change" ...

Answer (score 1):

Changing the question from "integral quadratic form represents zero" to "real quadratic form almost represents zero", changes the classical theorems (which eventually sum up to the Hasse-Minkowski theorem) to the Oppenheim conjecture, proved by Margulis in the late 80s, by completely different methods (instead of algebraic number theory, one uses Homogeneous Flows).

Answer (score 0):

Finding real solutions to an elliptic curve compared to finding integer solutions.

Comment: Not a small change, in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Let C be a finite collection of finite sets.  Further let C be closed under union.  Is it always the case that there is an element x which is in at least half the members of C?

The answer to this question is no.  If, however, the union of C is required to be nonempty, then the answer is unknown to me, and I suspect to many others.  (Look up union closed sets conjecture.)

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.02.26